# Weird problem with merge in R, producing NAs

Tags: r, merge

I have a data table, `first_median`,which includes a column `location`.
Another data table that has `location` and name of the `city` in it.

I want to merge them so the initial data table, `first_median`, gets the city names.

The problem is that it produces `NA`s for some of those. To be more clear,
the coordinate `44.03125_-123.09375` has the name `Eugene`. After merging,
the first two repetition of `44.03125_-123.09375` are mapped to `Eugene`, but the rest are mapped to `NA`.

Next weird part is that I convert the `first_median` to data frame, `(as.data.frame(first_median)`,
and then back to data table, `data.table(first_median)`, and then I do the merge, then it works!!!

Please take a look at the image.

### Any idea what is going on?

[image]

Also, I changed the code to

```
first_medians_merged_before <- merge(first_medians, LOI, by="location", 

all.x=T)
dput(head(first_medians_merged_before, 5))

first_medians <- as.data.frame(first_medians)
first_medians <- data.table(first_medians)
first_medians_merged_after <- merge(first_medians, LOI, by="location", all.x=T)
dput(head(first_medians_merged_after, 5))
```

To be more clear, and the outputs of the `dput` are below:

```
> dput(head(first_medians_merged_before, 5))
structure(list(location = c("44.03125_-123.09375", "44.03125_-123.09375", 
"44.03125_-123.09375", "44.03125_-123.09375", "44.03125_-123.09375"
), time_period = c("1950-2005", "1950-2005", "1979-2015", "1979-2015", 
"2006-2025"), emission = c("RCP 4.5", "RCP 8.5", "RCP 4.5", "RCP 8.5", 
"RCP 4.5"), median = c(72, 72, 68, 68, 78), city = c("Eugene", 
"Eugene", NA, NA, NA)), sorted = "location", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1028114e0>)
```

---

```
> dput(head(first_medians_merged_after, 5))
structure(list(location = c("44.03125_-123.09375", "44.03125_-123.09375", 
"44.03125_-123.09375", "44.03125_-123.09375", "44.03125_-123.09375"
), time_period = c("1950-2005", "1950-2005", "1979-2015", "1979-2015", 
"2006-2025"), emission = c("RCP 4.5", "RCP 8.5", "RCP 4.5", "RCP 8.5", 
"RCP 4.5"), median = c(72, 72, 68, 68, 78), city = c("Eugene", 
"Eugene", "Eugene", "Eugene", "Eugene")), sorted = "location", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1028114e0>)
>
```

Comment: Please check if the values are same or if there are leading/lagging spaces

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. We can't recreate a problem with your code from a picture of it.

Comment: That is not it. I have checked, also, converting the type back and forth between data frame and table will not kill the spaces in strings, if there is any. I just hoped, with low probability, someone have had this problem before!

Comment: Might location be a factor in the original `first_median`? It would help if you could include in your question the output of running `dput(head(first_medians_merged, 5))` so that we could inspect the object, vs. how it prints. Some objects print the same but are different under the hood.

Comment: @JonSpring The answer to your first question is no, it is not a factor, had checked that, and I edited the question to include the `dput` part of your question.

I will get back to this at night, and see, if I can produce a "reproducible" form of this problem, and investigate more!

Comment: I got `TRUE` from `identical(first_medians_merged_before[1,1], first_medians_merged_before[3,1])`, so the problem seems to be upstream of or during the merge.  Possibly warned about in ?merge: "This is intended to work with data frames with vector-like columns: some aspects work with data frames containing matrices, but not all."